# QML access tableview header's function

Tags: c++, qt, qml

By default, when i double-click on table's header splitter, it automatic resize to fit with column's content, or sort model when click on the header itself.

I don't know how to implement those function into a custom rowDelegate or table's 
model. Can anyone give me a hint please?

And thank for dropping by